# Playwright - Chai - Validate if String is Enabled

Tags: javascript, chai, playwright

I'm working with Javascript, Playwright and Chai assertions. When I try to validate if a button is enabled (Chai assertions) executions fails.

```
async wasEmail100CharactersFilled() {
    //expect(verifyEmailButton).to.not.be.disabled() //Not working
    should.exist(verifyEmailButton.toBeEnabled()) //Not working
  }
```

Verify email button is an String.

Can anybody help me with this?

**EDITED**

This is the element when is disabled:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary min-h-0 h-10 w-full rounded-full flex-shrink-0 capitalize  rounded-full normal-case disabled:cursor-not-allowed text-sm" xpath="1" disabled=""><i class="hidden h-6 w-0 "></i>Verify Email<i class="hidden h-6 w-0 "></i></button>
```

The same when it's enabled:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary min-h-0 h-10 w-full rounded-full flex-shrink-0 capitalize  rounded-full normal-case disabled:cursor-not-allowed text-sm" xpath="1"><i class="hidden h-6 w-0 "></i>Verify Email<i class="hidden h-6 w-0 "></i></button>
```

I still trying with this assertion for the String, but it's not working:

```
await page.$eval(verifyEmailButton, el => el.classList.contains("disabled"));
```

Comment: verifyEmailButton can not be an string, must be an element. And one more thing, can you share where did you find toBeEnabled method? What is the library you are using?

Comment: i have defined as string in another class. Is there any method for validating if is displayed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the only thing that worked for me:

```
if(await page.$eval(verifyEmailButton, el => el.disabled = true)){
            console.log("Button is Disabled")
        } else {throw Error("Button is Enabled");}
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
await expect(page.$('.btn')).toBeEnabled(true);
```

As you can see you has to set an element, not an string

Comment: I'm using the Chai expect. Not the Playwright expect. Didn't work in any way.

Comment: But verifyEmailButton is an string? verifyEmailButton can not be an string. Also, can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: Edited. And yes: This is a String and I want to validate this String with a Chai assertion.